# Prove if $a_n$ converges to $0$ and $b_n$ is bounded, then $a_n b_n$ converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

We have these two hypothesis:

$$\forall\epsilon_1>0, \exists n_0 | n>n_o \implies |a_n|<\epsilon_1$$
$$|b_n|<M$$
where $M$ is the sequence bound.

Therefore, I've used hypothesis 2 to multiply both sides in the hypothesis 1 so we have:

$$\forall\epsilon_1>0, \exists n_0 | n>n_o \implies |a_n b_n|<\epsilon_1M$$

then if we choose $\epsilon = \epsilon_1 M$ we have:

$$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists n_0 | n>n_o \implies |a_n b_n|<\epsilon$$

Am I right?

Comment: Looks correct, however I would word it a bit different and say (instead of "then if we choose") that "given $\epsilon$ we choose $\epsilon_1 = \epsilon/M$ to get $\ldots$"

Comment: @Winther thanks, good sugestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Take any $\epsilon >0$ then $|a_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{M}$, whenever $n> n_0$, for some $n_0 \in \mathbb N$, where $M$ is such that $|b_n|\leq M$ then

$$|a_n b_n|= |a_n||b_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{M} M = \epsilon $$

Comment: How did you find $|a_n|$ when epsilon is greater than 0?

Comment: From hypothesis 1.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the squeeze theorem.

If $|b_n|<M$ for all $n$, then
$$
-M|a_n|\le a_nb_n \le M|a_n|
$$
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, also $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=0$ and so
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}-M|a_n|=0=\lim_{n\to\infty}M|a_n|
$$

---

In your proof you aren't allowed to choose $\epsilon$, but you can choose $\epsilon_1$, which is quite different.

Given $\epsilon>0$, consider $n_0$ such that, for $n>n_0$, $|a_n|<\epsilon/M$.

Then, for $n>n_0$ we have
$$
|a_nb_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{M}M=\epsilon
$$

Comment: Second part is just what I said.

Comment: @AaronMaroja Not really: in your proof you're starting from an arbitrary $\epsilon_1$ and then choose $\epsilon$. You have to start from arbitrary $\epsilon$.

Comment: No, I didn't...

Comment: @AaronMaroja If I were to grade your proof, I'd not consider it correct.

Comment: Is that so?Why not?